# preg_replace() with a link

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I am trying to integrate a reply system like Twitter, where you can use "@usernameHere". I need to replace @usernameHere with a link to that user's profile. Can I do it with just `preg_replace()`. Something like this...?

```
$pattern = '/(?<![\w@])@([\w@]+(?:[.!][\w@]+)*)/';
$replacement = '<a href="profile?user='.$needle.'">Username</a>';
$string = "@mark, hey wanna hang?";
preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
```

How would I get the `$needle`? As in, how would I get the contents of what was replaced? The `$needle` in this situation would be `mark`

Is there anyway I could get it like `preg_match()`? Here is how I would get it with `preg_match()`.

```
preg_match('/(?<![\w@])@([\w@]+(?:[.!][\w@]+)*)/', $comment, $matches);
$matches[1] = $needle;
```

Comment: `'<a href="profile?user=$1">$1</a>'`, note that the `$1` is _inside_ the string.

Comment: Can you explain, @Wrikken?

Comment: This is your fourth question on that topic. Reading the manual might sometimes be quicker.

Comment: 4th question? Sorry, but I only recall asking a question on this topic once before?

Comment: Not, if we count the [deleted ones](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25336984/preg-match-the-symbol-and-word-with-it) with.

Comment: Ok, I get your point. I'll do a bit more reading in the manual when I come across something I get stumped on. Then I'll bring my question here if I don't clearly understand the manual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) states this clearly:

> ***replacement*** may contain references of the form \n or (since PHP 4.0.4) $n, with the latter form being the preferred one. Every such reference will be replaced by the text captured by the n'th parenthesized pattern. **n can be from 0 to 99, and \0 or $0 refers to the text matched by the whole pattern**. Opening parentheses are counted from left to right (starting from 1) to obtain the number of the capturing subpattern. To use backslash in replacement, it must be doubled ("\\" PHP string).

`$n` in regular expression replacements are references to what was matched by the nth [capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html).

So you would use `$1` here to reference what was matched by the first capturing group.

```
$replacement = '<a href="profile?user=$1">$1</a>';
```

Comment: I used `$replacement = '<a href="profile?user=$0">$0</a>';` and that worked for me because I wanted to use the whole pattern. But thanks for the explanation! Is there a way to exclude the "@" sign in the replacement?

Comment: OHH ok that makes more sense now. Thank you, I just had to re-read that paragraph on the replacement a few times.

Comment: Is there any way you can search the username in a database and return the id instead? My profile pages look more like "profile.php?id=2", but with this solution it would show "profile.php?id=username"